# How to copy rows from one Excel file to another with python

Tags: python, excel

I have attempted to search over and over but I cant find it. If it is exists I am sorry.

I want to open an existing excel file with a ton of rows. I want to copy every row into a list or something and then copy that into a new excel file.

But I plan to do this daily, so after the first time, I want to continue to copy all the rows from this excel file and appended it to the file.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using the `pandas` library.

Comment: Try using `os.rename`.

Comment: But I want to copy some of the rows not all in the file.